# How to delete everything between two duplicates in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am finding an augmenting path between two nodes using depthfirst and tracking the traversal along the way. However, I need to be able to delete everything between two duplicated indices in the traversal list. So if the list looked like
`[1,2,4,3,7,4,6]` where the start is 1 and the target is 6, I would need to output
`[1,2,4,6]`
I was thinking I could just use splice from the position of the first instance of the value up to the second, but I am having a hard time keeping track of when I find duplicates.
Any help would be awesome

Comment: What problem are you having keeping track? There are just two indices to keep track of, the first and the duplicate.

Comment: why does your pathfinder produce such a solution in the first place?

Comment: The augPath function just adds each node to a list until the target node is found, then it returns, and I try to process the list to delete duplicates and my terminal freezes everytime`

Comment: ```function augmentingPath(graph, start, end){
    traversal = [];
    traversal = augPath(graph[start],graph[end],graph);
    for( i = 0; i < traversal.length; i ++){
        for(j = 1; j < traversal.length;){
            if(traversal[i] == traversal[j]){
                traversal.splice(i, j-1);
            }
        }
    }
    return traversal;
}```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
array1 = [1,2,4,3,7,4,6,8,9];
array2= [];
start = 1;
end = 6;
array3 = array1.slice();

array1.splice(array1.indexOf(end) + 1, array1.length-1);  // Remove extra elements after End Value i.e after 6

array1.forEach((element,index)=> {
    if(element>=start && element<=end) {
        if (array1.includes(element,index + 1)) {
            array2 = []
            array2 = array1.slice(
            array1.splice(
                array1.indexOf(element) + 1,
                array1.indexOf(end)- array1.indexOf(element)))
                return
        } else {
            array2.push(element)    
        }
    }
});
array2.push(end);
```